# Longest common subsequence with at most one swap

Tags: longest-common-substring

Is there a good algorithm for calculating the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) where we consider two sequences identical if they can be transformed to one another with at most 1 swapping of subsequences (i.e. taking two non-overlapping subsequences of the same length and substituting them for each other)? For example `ABCDEFGHIJ` would be considered identical to `EFGHABCDIJ` but not to `ABCDEHFGIJ`. Or is there such an algorithm for subsequences of length one?

Comment: Have you tried extending the dynamic programming algorithm for LCS?

Answer (score 1):

Swapping two non-overlapping subsequences is same as swapping two non-overlapping substrings of one of the input strings.

A simple algorithm would be to guess the start and end points of the substrings that we want to swap, let them be (s1,t1) and (s2,t2), and run LCS using this swapped string. There are O(m^2*n^2) such guesses and each one takes O(m*n).